# crc8 undefined while compiling linux kernel module on Beaglebone black/Debian

Tags: linux, debian, drivers, kernel-modules, c

I am trying to use the device driver for a TI battery monitor BQ76PL536 on my beaglebone black(BBB). The driver code is located here: https://github.com/tommessick/bq76pl536 .

Although, the author had tested for a cross-compile Ubuntu toochain, I tried to compile the kernel module directly on my BBB.

I did

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.9-ti-r25
```

to install the relevant kernel headers, and then using the following `Makefile`

```
DRIVER = bq76pl536

ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
    obj-m += $(DRIVER).o
else
    PWD := $(shell pwd)

default:
ifeq ($(strip $(KERNELDIR)),)
    $(error "KERNELDIR is undefined!")
else
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR)  M=$(PWD) modules
endif
```

and I defined `KERNELDIR=/lib/modules/4.4.9-ti-r25/build/` . I am following the instructions as here: http://derekmolloy.ie/writing-a-linux-kernel-module-part-1-introduction/

and my output of `make` is :

```
make
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.9-ti-r25/build/      M=/var/lib/cloud9/bq76_driver/bq76pl536 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.9-ti-r25'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: "crc8_populate_msb"   [/var/lib/cloud9/bq76_driver/bq76pl536/bq76pl536.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "crc8" [/var/lib/cloud9/bq76_driver/bq76pl536/bq76pl536.ko] undefined!
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.9-ti-r25'
```

While the .o, .ko etc. files are created. When I try to load the module using `insmod` I get an error:

```
sudo insmod ./bq76pl536.ko 
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ./bq76pl536.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

My `dmesg` output is as under

```
dmesg | tail
[   21.564768] eqep 48304180.eqep: failed to get clock
[   21.605265] c_can_platform 481cc000.can: c_can_platform device registered (regs=fa1cc000, irq=207)
[   21.661309] c_can_platform 481d0000.can: c_can_platform device registered (regs=fa1d0000, irq=208)
[   21.768584] eqep: probe of 48304180.eqep failed with error -2
[161381.366409] bq76pl536: Unknown symbol crc8 (err 0)
[161381.366768] bq76pl536: Unknown symbol crc8_populate_msb (err 0)
[162501.175612] bq76pl536: Unknown symbol crc8 (err 0)
[162501.175973] bq76pl536: Unknown symbol crc8_populate_msb (err 0)
```

I cannot understand the origin of this error - compiler not being able to find functions: `crc8` and `crc8_populate_msb`, when they are defined in crc8.h, which is accessible in the headers: /linux/crc8.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error isn't coming from the compiler, it's coming from the linker. Header files only contain the declaration of functions, they don't contain the function's code, so having the function declared in a header isn't sufficient to execute it. The build-time [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) warns you that it hasn't found a place where the function is defined. When you try to load the module, the kernel performs the last linking steps. At that stage, all functions used by the loaded module must be defined by the running kernel. In your case, `crc8` is required by the module but not defined by the kernel so the module cannot be loaded.

The `crc8` function is an optional feature that must be enabled with [`CONFIG_CRC8` (“CRC8 function” under “Library routines”)](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/Kconfig?v=4.4) at build time. It may be loaded as a module also called `crc8`. Try

```
modprobe crc8
```

If this works then your installation has the `crc8` module. After compiling the `bq76pl536` and installing it under `/lib/modules`, run `depmod -a`; this generates a dependency file and after this loading the `bq76pl536` normally (i.e. with `modprobe bq76pl536`, not directly with `insmod`) will also load the `crc8` module.

If this doesn't work, then your installation doesn't have the `crc8` module, and you'll need to recompile a kernel with it. Use Ubuntu's packaging and configuration (except for changing that one configuration item). See the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) for a walkthrough. Since you've modified the configuration, make sure to add a version modifier in `debian.master/changelog` as explained on the wiki. Then reboot under the new kernel and recompile the `bq76pl536` module against the new kernel.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. `modprobe crc8` gave an error: Module crc8 not found. So I am guessing I will have to take the route two. I will accept your answer soon.  

If I understood it correctly, then I should plan to cross-compile the **debian** arm kernel on an Ubuntu x86 with the changed configuration.

Comment: I am accepting your answer but need the slight help with finishing. I am trying for Raspberry Pi as the new kernel installation is much simpler. I will try BBB as well. On Rpi, I made the necessary config changes to the kernel, and built it. Now when I run `modprobe crc8`, I do not get the error as before, and the crc8 module gets loaded. I compile the bq76pl536 code and it compiles without warning. I did `depmod -a`. However, `modprobe bq76pl536` and `modprobe bq76pl536.ko` result in module not found error. I also tried insmod, but to no avail.

Comment: Also, I do not know what you mean by "installing it under `/lib/modules` ". I just ran `make` in the bq76 directory and then `depmod -a`. Is there an intermediate step of _installation_ in between ?

Comment: @ChintanPathak `modprobe` looks for the module file under `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)`. Run `sudo make modules_install` from the module directory to install it there.

Comment: The Makefile: https://github.com/tommessick/bq76pl536/blob/master/Makefile for the module doesnt have a rule for target module_install so it throws the error, when I do make modules_install from the bq76pl536 directory where I compiled the module and .ko file is located.